# how to showbottomsheet above keyboard while typing in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have taken a floating action button to show showModelbottomsheet,

but when I click on textfield for entry, keyboard coming on top of the bottom sheet,

how to scroll this bottom sheet above keyboard layout,

here is my code

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Sqflite with Provider'),),
      body: getbody(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){
          showModalBottomSheet<void>(context: context, builder: (context){
            return EntryForm();
          });

        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget getbody() {
    return Text('Welcome to Provider');
  }
}
```

and entryform widget

```
class _EntryFormState extends State<EntryForm> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(),
          TextField(),
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text('Save Record'))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set `isScrollControlled` to `true` like this:

```
showModalBottomSheet<void>(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      builder: (context){
            return EntryForm();
      }
);
```

then in `EntryForm` add padding to `SingleChildScrollView`:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  padding:
          EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
  child: ...
),
```

Comment: it does not work when I wrap entry form inside a container with some height

Comment: Yes ur given code is working,,, but if I wrap entry form inside a container and apply height 200 or any,,, it stops working

Comment: in that case you need to add that padding to your container which has height of 200. @IrfanGanatra